# how to set different rules for a path and its child in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm developing an application which needs to keep data separate for each user, which only they can access.
I know how this can be done with the following code:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how can a new user be added if /users path is inaccessible?
If I set rules for /users path, it will cascade down to each uid path.
If we can set different rules for parent and child in some way, that could solve this problem.

Is this possible and secure? or please suggest another way to add users.
Still a beginner in firebase, please help.

Comment: The rules do allow a user to read and write their own node under users, which will create it if necessary.  Are you observing something different?  If so, edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: yes it works. I tried it in the rules playground. thanks!